# How to check characters after a specific part of a string in C#?

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine

I am trying to find a specific value inside a string, and then check the characters which come after the value.

I got the first part and can find the values I need but want to check after every value I find if any of the ten characters in front of it in the string are numbers or not.

here is the first part I got so far:

```
     public class Text_Value : MonoBehaviour
 {  
     [SerializeField]
     private TMP_Text Text;
 
     public List<string> Values = new List<string>();
 
     private int ChestCircumference;
 
     private int BodyHeight;
 
     private int HighHipCircumference;
 
     private int BellyCircumference;
 
     private int CharacterIndex = 0;
 
 
     // Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
     {
         StartCoroutine(GetValues());
     }
 
     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
         
     }
 
 
     IEnumerator GetValues()
     {
         if (Text.text == "No Data")
         {
             yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
 
             Debug.Log("Text Value Finder: Wating For Text Data");
 
             StartCoroutine(GetValues());
         }
         else if (Text.text != "No Data")
         {
             foreach (string value in Values)
             {
                 if (Text.text.Contains(value))
                 {
                     Debug.Log("Value Found: " + value);
                 }
                 else if (!Text.text.Contains(value))
                 {
                     Debug.Log("Missing Value: " + value);
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 
 }
```

I think I need to use a loop inside the foreach loop, one that will go over the next ten characters, but not sure how to do it.

An example of the string would be:

> "Collar Circumference":39.102776,"Neck Base Circumference":42.982479"

Comment: All your `else if` should rather simply be `else` .. currently you redundantly make the same expensive checks twice .. after the first check you already know whether the condition is fulfilled or not ...

Comment: You might rather want to use [`Regex.Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match) so you can find all matches of given patterns and return match groups like which exact match was found and what the numeric value is before it .. would be easier to answer this if you could tell us what exact matches you are looking for in your string, including an example of how the string is expected to look like

Comment: Can you provide an example string, this would help

Comment: @Yot what do you mean? `Regex.Match` is exactly for that: Finding a certain pattern in your string .. just that it is way more flexible than searching for exact matches since you can define one abstract pattern that is valid for any of your matches if they all follow a certain similar pattern

Comment: There is a lot of ambiguity in your question which makes it hard to determine what you actually want... can you post an example of the values and string please?

Comment: @Stefan derHugo sure:

"Collar Circumference":39.102776,"Neck Base Circumference":42.982479.....

Comment: this looks like a partial JSON string, is that correct?

Comment: Sounds like you rather want to use JSON?

Comment: yes, its part of a json file

Answer (score 1):

As said you could use [`Regex.Matches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=net-6.0) like e.g.

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(Text.text, "\"(.*?)\":(.*?)(?=,|$)");
foreach(var match in matches)
{
    var key = match.Groups[1];
    var valueString = match.Groups[2];
    if(float.TryParse(valueString, out var value))
    {
        Debug.Log($"Found match for {key} with value = {value}");
    }
}
```

See [Regex Example and explanation](https://regex101.com/r/W47pQq/1)

---

However, if this is actually a JSON then you should rather use a proper c# representation and actually parse the JSON e.g. depending on the complexity of your JSON simply using the built-in [`JsonUtility`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html)

Assuming you have access to the JSON generation and can rather use names without spaces like

```
{
    "ChestCircumference":12.34,
    "BodyHeight":1.23,
    "HighHipCircumference":0.23,
    "BellyCircumference":0.34567,
    "CharacterIndex": 3
}
```

In your case you could e.g. wrap your values like

```
// The class name doesn't matter in JSON
[Serializable]
public class Config
{
     public float ChestCircumference;
     public float BodyHeight;
     public float HighHipCircumference;
     public float BellyCircumference;
     public int CharacterIndex = 0;
}
```

and then simply do

```
var config = JsonUtility.FromJson<Config>(jsonString);
```

Or if changing the JSON is not an option use [Newtonsoft JSON](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@2.0/manual/index.html) like e.g.

```
{
    "Chest Circumference":12.34,
    "Body Height":1.23,
    "High Hip Circumference":0.23,
    "Belly Circumference":0.34567,
    "Character Index": 3
}
```

Then

```
[Serializable]
public class Config
{
     [JsonProperty ("Chest Circumference")]
     public float ChestCircumference;
     [JsonProperty ("Body Height")]
     public float BodyHeight;
     [JsonProperty ("High Hip Circumference")]
     public float HighHipCircumference;
     [JsonProperty ("Belly Circumference")]
     public float BellyCircumference;
     [JsonProperty ("Character Index")]
     public int CharacterIndex = 0;
}
```

And then do

```
var config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Config>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to access specific values, is to parse the string and put it in a dictionary, where the name of the part is used as key:

```cs
string input =
    "\"Collar Circumference\":39.102776,\"Neck Base Circumference\":42.982479";

var dict = input.Split(",\"")
    .Select(p => p.TrimStart('"').Split("\":"))
    .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => Double.Parse(x[1]));
```

This test ...

```cs
double collar = dict["Collar Circumference"];
double neckBase = dict["Neck Base Circumference"];
Console.WriteLine(collar);
Console.WriteLine(neckBase);
foreach (var entry in dict) {
    Console.WriteLine($"\"{entry.Key}\" = {entry.Value}");
}
```

... prints:

> 39.102776
> 42.982479
> "Collar Circumference" = 39.102776
> "Neck Base Circumference" = 42.982479

This assumes that all values can be expressed as `double`. If this is not the case, just keep them as string:

```cs
...
.ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

2 versions, both outputting the correct result:

##### Using .NET 5 `System.Text.Json`

This would work:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var jsonString = @"{ ""Collar Circumference"":39.5678,""NeckBase Circumference"":42.876}";
        
        //parse it
        var yourObject = System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString);
        //retrieve the value
        var circumReference = yourObject.RootElement.GetProperty("Collar Circumference");
        
        Console.WriteLine(circumReference);
    }
}
```

---

##### Using Newtonsoft version:

Install package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/13.0.1

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var jsonString = @"{ ""Collar Circumference"":39.5678,""NeckBase Circumference"":42.876}";
        dynamic obj = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsonString);
        
        Console.WriteLine(obj["Collar Circumference"].ToString());
    }
}
```